# Grid View Not Displaying,

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        getControls();
    }
}

public void getControls()
{
    string connn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RiskRegisterDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    DataTable ds = DB.GetDataTable("Select * from ControlTable", connn);

    // GridView11.DataSource = ds;
    GridView11.DataBind(); 
}
```

I have tried using `AutoGenerationColumn` as "true" and "false" both, but I'm not getting the gridview to display in browser while running the program.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView11" runat="server" 
     AutogenerateColumns="False" Cellpadding="4" 
     CssClass="auto-style6" DataKeyNames="Control_ID" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
     Forecolor="#333333" Gridlines="None" Width="1124px" >
```

Comment: Gee, what is with the \\* in that SQL? Never seen that before? Try "SELECT * from ControlTable"

Comment: Sorry I have mistakenly Typed \ Here,  "Select * From ControlTable" is my Actual Code.

Comment: ok, then you need to un-comment the data source line you have for the Gridview. You always need both the datasource to be set, and then databind.  Your datasource line of code is commented out.

Comment: when Uncommenting this line, it gives me error (Additional information: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView11'.  Remove one definition.) , As I have added the DataSource from Design view.

Comment: The message quite much tells you what to do! - you should have posted some of the grid view markup. Remove the datasource setting in the GV markup, since you now setting the GV data in code behind. You can't have both - and the error message even tells you what to do!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try you code say like this:

```
public void getControls()
{
    string strCon =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RiskRegisterDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT * FROM ControlTable";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: I don't know what's the issue,  i am using my same code in different pages and its working, but showing error in only one page, Is there any Setting issue ?

Comment: If you  removed the datasource="xxxx" in the markup? Then next thing to check is the page load event. Wrap the code that loads up the GV in a if (!IsPostBack) {your gv load code goes here}. this will usually fix this issue.